# For most halachot that require a specific number of people present, do Siamese twins count as 2 people or as 1 person?

Tags: halacha, twins

Let's say you have Siamese twins - two heads coming out of a single torso - one set of arms and one set of legs.

Is this human considered as 2 people or one for purposes of:

- minyan counting
- testimony requiring 2 witnesses. (Assume that this is a case where the 2 witnesses may be related to each other. I think that *Kiddush hachodesh* may be an example. Perhaps, criminal case testimony may work, also.)

The above two are just examples of what I can think of at the moment regarding places where something requires a specific number of people for an event to occur. Feel free to add others.

Comment: Two witnesses can NOT be related to each other ever.

Comment: The gemoro in menachos does dicuss this.